# Issues with makefile

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling

To make use of a library I have to alter a makefile to make use the cross-compiler *arm-none-eabi-g++* instead of *arm-none-eabi-gcc*; however, for some odd reason I continually receive a `No rule to make target` error. I removed the dependencies and only left the start-up code and main, I also attempted to use the absolute path to the files. However, I continue to receive the error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
PROJECT_NAME=test-liv

BUILDDIR = build

LIBDIR = ../common
DEVICE = $(LIBDIR)/STM32F4xx
CORE = $(LIBDIR)/CMSIS
PERIPH = $(LIBDIR)/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver
PROJHEADERS = inc
PROJ_LIBDIR = lib

#SOURCES = src/main.cpp
SOURCES = startup_stm32f4xx.S
SOURCES += system_stm32f4xx.c
SOURCES += LibraryHacks.cpp

SOURCES += src/main.cpp
#SOURCES += $(PERIPH)/src/
#PROJECT SOURCES
#SOURCES += $(PROJ_LIBDIR)/src/


OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(abspath $(basename $(SOURCES)))))

INCLUDES += -I$(DEVICE) \
            -I$(PROJHEADERS) \
            -I$(CORE) \
            -I$(PERIPH)/inc \
            -I$(PROJ_LIBDIR)/inc \
            -Isrc \
            -I.

ELF = $(BUILDDIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME).elf
HEX = $(BUILDDIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME).hex
BIN = $(BUILDDIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME).bin

CXX = arm-none-eabi-g++
LD = arm-none-eabi-g++
AR = arm-none-eabi-ar
OBJCOPY = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
GDB = arm-none-eabi-gdb
SIZE = arm-none-eabi-size

CXXFLAGS  = -O0 -g -Wall -I.\
   -std=c++11 -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb-interwork \
   -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard \
   $(INCLUDES) -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER

SEMIHOSTING_FLAGS = --specs=rdimon.specs -lc -lrdimon

LDSCRIPT = stm32_flash.ld
LDFLAGS += -T$(LDSCRIPT) -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 

$(BIN): $(ELF)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

$(HEX): $(ELF)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

$(ELF): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SEMIHOSTING_FLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS)
    $(SIZE) $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.S
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

flash: $(BIN)
    st-flash write $(BIN) 0x8000000

debug: $(ELF)
    $(GDB) -tui $(ELF)

openocd: $(ELF)
    openocd -f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg

all: $(HEX) $(BIN) $(ELF)

functions: all

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf build
```

**EDIT**: Full ERROR message I removed other dependencies and left LibraryHacks and main and depending whichone is first it still gives me the same error

```
mkdir -p build//*Removed*/
arm-none-eabi-g++ -c -O0 -g -Wall -I. -std=c++11 -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb-interwork -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -I../common/STM32F4xx -Iinc -I../common/CMSIS -I../common/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -Ilib/inc -Isrc -I. -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER /*Removed*/startup_stm32f4xx.S -o build//*Removed*/startup_stm32f4xx.o
mkdir -p build//*Removed*/
arm-none-eabi-g++ -c -O0 -g -Wall -I. -std=c++11 -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb-interwork -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -I../common/STM32F4xx -Iinc -I../common/CMSIS -I../common/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -Ilib/inc -Isrc -I. -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER /*Removed*/system_stm32f4xx.c -o build//*Removed*/system_stm32f4xx.o
make: *** No rule to make target `build//*Removed*/LibraryHacks.o', needed by `build/hx8352a-lcd.elf'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Their are also no spaces in the path

Comment: And if you take this makefile and replace arm-none-eabi-g++ with arm-none-eabi-gcc, it works, correct?

Comment: when the project was only C yes but, now when is witch back to  arm-none-eabi-gcc and modify the flag to c99 it gives me the exact same output

Comment: Well, you have a rule there to make `.o` files from `.c` files, a rule right after that one to make `.o` files from `.S` files, and a conspicuous lack of anything to do with `.cpp` files. Are you invoking make in a way that disables [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) (or using some version built without an implicit `%.o : %.cpp` rule)?

Comment: built in implicit rules won't help because he doesn't want to build `%.o` from `%.cpp`, he wants to build `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o` from `%.cpp`, which is entirely different (from make's point of view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
```

describes to make how to create a file `$(BUILDDIR)/foo.o` from `foo.c`.  But you now want to compile a `.cpp` file.  Just changing the compiler variable in the recipe from `$(CC)` to `$(CXX)` doesn't change description of targets or prerequisites!  You need to add a *new* rule telling make how to compile your `.cpp` files:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Also, you should probably put back the `$(CC)` compile invocation in the `%.c` recipe; it's generally not a good idea to compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: thank you everything builds correctly now i used gcc for c and asm files and g++ for c++ files. I would not have realized the mistake